# Would there be an interference pattern if slits and source are light years apart?

Tags: speed-of-light, wavefunction, double-slit-experiment, interference

Imagine I replicate Feynman's double slit experiment so that the distance between the slits are light years away from each other, and the source which is far, far away give out a single electron at any one time. I remembered hearing from someone somewhere that the lonely electron can pass through the two slits at once and even shockingly it can tell if one of the slit got clogged!!! (suggesting information can travel faster than light) Sounds like quantum entanglement but involves only 1 particle instead... is this scenario theoretically sounds? Also can the wavefunction of an electron be that big?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It still works *if* the coherence length of the light source is longer than the path length difference.  There are lasers whose coherence length is on the order of a kilometer.  A sodium vapor lamp has a coherence length of about six tenths of a millimeter.  White light has a coherence length on the order of a micron.

Comment: I was thinking about a gravitational lens, where there can be 2 paths from a distant source to detector--but I guess the coherence length is too short.

Comment: Yes, probably the two paths would differ by far more than the coherence length of the source light.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the wavefunction of an electron can be infinitely big.
Yes, the double-slit interferometer can work at a range of light-years -- as long as the electron (or other particle) doesn't interact with anything that can unpredictably alter its wavefunction  on its way to the detector.
BUT: information cannot travel faster than the speed of light.  Nothing is "instantaneously" communicated. Entanglement/quantum correlations *are* information; they cannot *carry* information the way light beams or radio waves can.  Popular accounts are almost always, it seems, horrendously misleading on this subject.

Comment: Take "infinitely" with a grain of salt.  The universe is (probably) not infinitely big.

Comment: how about I shift the screen nearer to the slits so the path is shorter between slits and screen compared to one slit and another slit? (no blocking of slit in this case)

Answer (score 1):

I will turn my comments to an answer:

The double slit interference does not involve only one particle. It is the solution of the boundary value scattering problem " electron impinging on specific two slits", the boundary values being the width and separation of slits, the distance to the detecting plane. The slits themselves are defined by the edges of order of 10^23 quantum mechanical atoms and molecules . [The one electron at a time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) experiment shows how the probabilistic interference pattern appears by accumulation of random looking hits .

[image: dblslitel]

The top frame shows individual electron hits . Each individual electron can be used to estimate the probability for hitting in the (x, y) plane. The hits look random. It is the quantum mechanical wavefunction  of the beam electrons that allows the build up of the interference pattern inherent in the quantum mechanical solution of the boundary value problem.

For light year distances, the beam will have dispersed enormously, and even if one managed to get an electron (that has not interacted on the way) to reach the  slits it will just give one of the random dots as in the first frame above, according to the probability distribution for (x,y) hits as it appears in the last slit.

It is not an experiment that can be done.

The "waving" of the wavefunction is dependent on the energy of the electron and the boundary conditions of the slit and detecting plane, so the distance should be irrelevant. I suppose if one waited for a long time for the same energy electrons to accumulate from the light years away beam, one could reproduce the frames shown above.

Comment: The proposed Breakthrough Starshot laser would provide plenty of photons over a distance of a few light years, though it's not yet clear that they have figured out a way to obtain coherence length grwater than a few centimeters.